# Flutter several tabs each with a navigator, push route from one tab to another

Tags: flutter, navigator

I'm stuck with a situation in flutter. I have a two tabs, each tab has a navigator. Each navigator can show a set of pages.

When on the first tab I would like to click a link on page one and be taken to the second tab and shown page three. Effectively deep linking from a page under tab one to a page under tab three. When navigating to page three, tab two should become active.

[image: Tab Structure]

I have the tabs hosted in the typical way using a tab controller:

```
child: DefaultTabController(
  length: 2,
  child: Scaffold(
    appBar: TabBar(
      tabs: const [
        Tab(text: 'HOME'),
        Tab(text: 'MENU'),
      ],
    ),
    body: TabBarView(
      children: <Widget>[
        HomeScreen(),
        MenuScreen(),
      ],
    ),
  ),
),
```

From inside a page with a tab, I can access the tab controller by doing:

```
onTap: () async {
  TabController tab = DefaultTabController.of(context);
  tab.animateTo(1);
},
```

But I'm unsure of how to access the TAB2's navigator to push the page to have it navigate to page 3.

Feel like I'm missing something simple. Appreciate any advice :)

Comment: are you able to solve, I have same situation and need help

Comment: I ended up using nested routes https://vrouter.dev/guide/Examples/Nesting the parent contains the tab and the inside is the page being loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using vRouter with nested routes: https://vrouter.dev/guide/Examples/Nesting